# Recursive read of TCollection

Tags: c++, recursion, tcollection, tcollectionitem

I'm very bad with recursion, never used it before. I know the theory of it .. not that that helps :)) For my problem i have a structure of TCollection that contains TCollection and TCollectionItem etc .. I have to write a recursion function that will read all my TCollectionItems.
Here is graphical view:

TCollection->TCollectionItem(s)->TCollection->TCollectionItem(s)

TCollection can have 1 or even 2,3 TCollection's under him OR none.

Here are few more examples:

TCollection->TCollectionItem

TCollection->TCollectionItem->TCollection->TCollectionItem->TCollection->TCollectionItem

etc ..

Please tell me if i described the problem badly, i probably did .. please ask if something is unclear :)

Thanks for the support!

Comment: methods prototypes to iterate over TCollection ?

Comment: how to know a TCollectionItems owns a TCollection ?

Comment: TCollectionItems owns a TCollection if it's Count property is larger then 0.

Comment: TCollectionItem does not have a Count property, and even if it did, it would not be incremented if the TCollectionItem owned its own child TCollection objects.

Comment: TCollection has property Count, not TCollectionItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated the prototypes of the TCollection methods so as to enumerate and to read your TCollectionItems, and other needed details.

However, this is definitely solved by: [The Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

The aim of this pattern is to traverse a recursive form, and to forward a call on a composite onto its composants and so on, until that reaches the leaves ( TCollectionItems with an empty TCollection in your case)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to recursively access child `TCollection` objects, without knowing the class types of the owning `TCollectionItem` objects so you can type-cast them, is to use the VCL's RTTI information.

In C++Builder versions prior to XE, VCL-based RTTI is only available for `__published` properties.  Given a `TCollectionItem` (or any general `TObject`) object pointer, you can use the `GetPropList()` function declared in `TypInfo.hpp` to retreive a list of that object's published property information.  You can then loop through that list, checking for any properties that report a TypeKind value of `tkClass`.  When you find one, use the `GetObjectProp()` function to retreive that property's `TObject` pointer value, and then use `dynamic_cast` to make sure it is really a `TCollection` object before you access its child `TCollectionItem` objects.

In C++Builder 2010, a new Enhanced RTTI system was introduced, declared in `Rtti.hpp`, that provides information for all members of a class, including non-published properties and fields.  With this enhanded RTTI, a child `TCollection` does not need to be declared as a `__published` property anymore.  Under this system, you would use the `TRttiContext` class to access a `TRttiType` object for your recursion's starting `TCollectionItem` object, then use the `TRttiType::GetFields()` and `TRttiType::GetProperties()` methods to look for child `TRttiField` and `TRttiProperty` items that report a TypeKind of `tkClass`, then use the `TRttiField::GetValue()` and `TRttiProperty::GetValue()` methods to get the `TObject` object pointer that can be type-casted to a `TCollection` pointer with `dynamic_cast`.